# Does the new iPod Touch (iOS 4.1 / 4 gen) require that you jail break it to use a Blue Tooth keyboard?

Tags: ipod-touch, keyboard, bluetooth

I already have a [BT keyboard](http://hubpages.com/hub/Rocketfish_Bluetooth_Wireless_Keyboard_and_Mouse_Multimedia_Pack) and I don't really want to buy a new one, so my question is, will the BT keyboard I already have work with an ipod touch?

Or will I need to use a proprietary Apple solution for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A 4th generation iPod Touch (or an iPhone 3GS or iPhone 4) running iOS 4.1 supports third-party bluetooth keyboards.

Comment: Nice!  Do you have one?

Comment: I have tested my iPhone 3GS with an Apple Wireless Keyboard. You will most likely have to unpair the keyboard from any computer it is paired with before pairing it with the iPod Touch.